# Node js - How to return a boolean

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm trying to return a boolean 0 or 1 but doesn't work.

How can i do that?

```
    checkKitReference(req, res)
  {
    var ref = req.params.ref;
    console.log("SELECT ref FROM st WHERE ref="+ref);
    request.query("SELECT ref FROM st WHERE ref='"+ref+"'",(err, records) => {
      console.log(err);
      if(records !== '')
      {
        return 0;
      }
      else
      {
        return 1;
      }
    });
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to add a callback function to your function. Then you call such callback with the value `0` or `1`.

Comment: So you want to return a response of "0" or "1" to the browser? Btw, "boolean" usually means "true" or "false", even if internally in some languages they are stored as 0 and 1 values.

Comment: `0` and `1` are numbers, not booleans (which are `true` and `false`) … but you're problem here is that you are trying to return from an asynchronous function.